# Sprint 177 (21 October 2020) release date?

Tags: azure-devops

I understood that Azure DevOps Service Sprint 177 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-177-update) would be released on 21 October, however, it still shows that we are on 176. Does anyone have an idea on when the update will be made? There are some changes I really want ;)

Comment: See this message in the bottom: "These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks."

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that big purple banner completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, they have a 3 week sprints, judging from that link, so add 21 days to 21 october. and then add couple of days on top of that, for the changes to roll out.

Comment: I assumed the date was the sprint end date, not start date. Thanks for the clarification.